# How to provide ordering and sorting functionality in a table for creating reports

Tags: usability, data-tables, sorting, ordering

My purpose is to create a report which shows the size of set/s.

For this, I am taking in minimum size & maximum size for each set.

Along with it, I am supposed to capture the order type and the sequence so that it translates to something like `ORDER BY SET1 ASC, SET2_TO_3 ASC, SET1_TO_2 DESC, SET3 DESC, SET2 DESC`

I have come up with the below prototype - which is undoubtedly "ugly" - especially the ordering pieces.

Though I can live with the text-box/es for setting size range - I am more than sure there must be a better way to implement the ordering functionality.

[image]
Any pointer would be a great help.
Thanks.

Comment: You used the 'usability' tag, but then suggest that the problem is that your UI is "ugly". Ugliness isn't a factor in usability, unless it keeps the UI  from meeting its stated goals. What are the goal(s) of this UI, and how does your mockup fail to meet it/them? As far as I see, the goal is to the show the size of set(s) and your mockup seems to do this fine.

Comment: Tables might seem boring, but the are also perfect for presenting certain types of information. Changing to some other type of element because you're not inspired, would be design for designs sake, not for the sake of functionality.  If your problem is with things like typography and the spacing of the elements - if you just want to make things shiny - then you have a design problem, not a usability problem.

Comment: How many orders will you need to shift in the sequence column, on average? When you say 'ordering functionality' are you referring to the overall UI, or the Sequence function itself?

Comment: @dennislees I am relatively new to this forum - maybe my usage of 'usability' tag is not appropriate here.As you already mentioned - the mockup meets all the requirement.My concern is to look for option/s to make it 'shiny'.I agree - this is a design problem, not a usability problem.Thanks for your response.

Comment: @MikeM I am referring to the "Order Type" and "Sequence" function here. I am looking for some UI elements which can be used to make it look more intuitive/friendly - if possible.Thanks for your response.

Comment: What is the purpose of Filter max/min size? Also, which operations prevail in your typical cases?

Comment: @RomanSusi  It filters the record/s which falls within the range specified.If the min/max is set as 10/20 for set1 - then I intend to show records for SET1 which are within 10 to 20 MB for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### For reordering the Sequence, try allowing direct manipulation in addition to text input.

You can take a page from Netflix, in which they have a queue order function.

Netflix users can order their queue as needed, with emphasis here on quickly arranging the most desired movies at the top.

[image]

There's a couple of methods you can offer:

- Numerical input (Just type in the sequence number)
- Drag and drop rows
- a 'Top' button to shoot it into the first position

You have a lot of room in your sequence inputs. You can save space by giving them a width that suggests the maximum digits encountered (i.e. if there's maybe 50 max you only need an input for 2 digits).

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftVXds.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

You can show the other options on hover, similar to the Grab handles on Gmail, combined w/ netflix 'Top' indicator.

**Sorting**

For the sorting, (unless I'm misunderstanding), it looks like you have text inputs.

Since there's only two values, you could do a dropdown to save space (and prevent input errors), and hint at the sort order implications in a lighter text to avoid confusion.

Comment: I believe order type is for ASCcending and DESCending sorting. Why do you have a number there?

Comment: Ah! my bad; i was focusing on the sequence ordering interaction. :)

Comment: @MikeM Thanks a lot for the detailed answer and for your time.All your comments make perfect sense.The comments really made the picture more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This (a bit bloated) example is from one of the Zope/Plone management views. You will have less options per row, but if drag-n-drop possibilities are limited in the UI toolkit, this approach may be quite usable.

[image]

Of course, "to the top" (⤒) and "to the bottom" (⤓) buttons can be added or even "go to Nth position" input.

Instead of ASC/DESC, visual markers can be used as well, eg, like those from Twitter Bootstrap 3:

[image]

Just make sure they are not confused with move up/down actions by placing them inside. Can be doubled by asc/desc text if it is appropriate.

For sizes, rangeslider (if available in the UI toolkit), if not - single sliders, if not even that - numeric inputs.

There maybe Select/Unselect all rows, if that is common operation.

This answer assumes limited UI toolkit functionality.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and your inputs.The range slider is definitely worth implementing.I will give it a shot.